# Android Firebase Query Issue

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Data sample:

```
 {
  "families" : {
    "4039738864" : {
      "2019-11-09" : {
        "-LtGOEjR-u_RKbXCiO2d" : {
          "messageDate" : "2019-11-09",
          "messageText" : "Test 1",
          "messageTime" : "11:20",
          "messageUser" : "dadio"
        },
        "-LtI2urxYkILHrYZdtmv" : {
          "messageDate" : "2019-11-09",
          "messageText" : "Hey man how is it going?",
          "messageTime" : "19:06",
          "messageUser" : "dadio"
        },
```

Basically a list of message objects under the day they were created. What I want is to pull back 10 days worth of messages (latest 10 days).

I have tried this Query:

```
Query query = familyRef.child(familyKey).orderByKey().startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate).limitToLast(10);


adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<ChatMessage, ChatHolder>(options) {

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public ChatHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                final View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

                return new ChatHolder(view);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChatHolder chatHolder, int i, @NonNull ChatMessage chatMessage) {

                //TODO: .toLocalDateTime() all dates
```

But this does pull back the child objects just the actual date nodes.

Any ideas?

Comment: You only showed how you declare the query, not how you process the data. Please edit your question to show what listener you attach to the query, what output you're getting (log statements typically work best), and what output you expected to get.

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Added the adapter I am using which does the listener.  The data I get back is an array of dates "2019-11-09", "2019-11-13", etc..

Comment: @AlexMamo any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like the expected behavior to me. The FirebaseUI adapter deals with the child nodes that match the query you pass in.

Since you pass a query on the `/families/$familyid` to the adapter, one view holder gets instantiated for each matching child, which are dates.

If you want to show a list of messages between two dates, your current data structure doesn't work well for that. Instead, consider storing your data like this:

```
  "families" : {
    "4039738864" : {
      "-LtGOEjR-u_RKbXCiO2d" : {
        "messageDate" : "2019-11-09",
        "messageText" : "Test 1",
        "messageTime" : "11:20",
        "messageUser" : "dadio"
      },
      "-LtI2urxYkILHrYZdtmv" : {
        "messageDate" : "2019-11-09",
        "messageText" : "Hey man how is it going?",
        "messageTime" : "19:06",
        "messageUser" : "dadio"
      },
      "-LtI2urxYkILHrYZdtmx" : {
        "messageDate" : "2019-11-10",
        "messageText" : "Totes good!",
        "messageTime" : "09:11",
        "messageUser" : "puf"
      },
```

In the above restructured data I've removed the "date" level from your JSON. Since you already have the date in each message, no data is lost, and you can now implement you use case with FirebaseUI.

With this data structure you can query for the same date range as before with:

```
Query query = familyRef.child(familyKey).orderByChild("MessageDate").startAt(startDate).endAt(endDate).limitToLast(10);
```

---

If you don't want to restructure your data, you will have to create a custom adapter to handle the use-case. You'll need to attach your own listener to the data structure, parse the messages for each day from the `DataSnapshot`, and update the data in your adapter.

Comment: Thanks. Will mark this as accepted as I had already restructured my data in the same way you suggest. Thanks for the proper query.

Answer (score 0):

you can get data of a single date like 
    `Query query = familyRef.child(familyKey).orderByKey().whereEqualTo("startDate", startDate).limitToLast(10);`

Comment: replace it with whatever key you have for your startDate in your database